# DC power across a 'hinged' surface

Tags: circuit-design

I am trying to build a 'self-lighted' chess board. It is a folding chess board and I need to get 5 v DC from one side to the other, across the hinged part. I want to use just one power source but cant visualize how to get wiring across the folding part. Any ideas?

Comment: you may have written your post on a device that has an electrical connection between two folding parts

Comment: If the board is made of a non-conducting material then use two metal hinges and connect wires to each leaf of each hinge.

Comment: Wires bend...flat wires bend more neatly.

Comment: Solid wires bend once or a few times, then break. Ordinary stranded wires can bend many times without breaking. Wires with very many fine strands, like you get in meter test leads, can be flexed until you die of old age.

Comment: Rigid-flex PCB?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

Use magnetic contacts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use two hinges... these should be made of metal and have a good enough contact to transmit the current for your LEDs. So you have your +5V and 0V, on on each hinge. No need for more complication.

Since these will be exposed, short circuit protection is necessary.